# An array of char pointer & an array of string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor, char

I want to make a Class Color, and declare 2 Class Color objects to store a list of warm colors and cold colors respectively.

How do i initialize an array of char pointer and define it in the constructor in C++?

.h

```
Const int MAX = 5;

Class Color {

  Char* list[MAX];
  Int numList;
}
```

.cpp

```
//default constructor
Color() {
  list[MAX] = nullptr;
  numList = 0;
}

//custom constructor
Color(char* list_, int numList_) {
  for (int i = 0; i < num_List_; i++) {
    list[i] = list_[i];
  }

  numList = numList_;
}
```

main.cpp

```
//declaring 2 objects of Class Color
Color warm_color;
Char warmList = {red, pink, orange, yellow, brown};

Color cold_color;
Char coldList = {“green”, “blue”, “navy”};

warm_color = Color(warmList, 5);
cold_color = Color(coldList, 3);
```

Comment: Please post real code. Either you've invented something called `Char` and completely failed to describe it, or you really meant `char`. If you don't post the code you actually have you just going to get answers pointing out the errors in the code you posted, instead of the errors in the code you are really working with.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. why do you want to use a pointer to an array of `char`? Why not just `char list[MAX];`? Do you know of the existence of [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Comment: C++ is a case-sensitive language. Also you're declaring methods of `class Color` as if you were declaring normal functions. You need to use complete qualified id of the methods, i.e. `Color::Color()`.

Comment: You should really look for a good introductory book to C++

Comment: There's a lot of obvious confusion here, this looks vaguely like C++ but it isn't actually C++. As others have suggested, a good C++ reference book will help you out a lot. This is absolutely essential when learning a language as nuanced and complex as C++ is.

Comment: Note that string “green” requires 6 bytes to store, not 5. Because you need a /0 char at end.  Also C++ can't work with capitalization, not sure if that is real code or you used editor that isn't meant for it (looks like VB\C# editor)

Comment: One piece of advice, which I think will help whatever the state of your real code. Forget about pointers, use `std::string` instead. Doesn't matter whether you're a beginner or experienced, in general it's better to avoid pointers.

Comment: all the syntax errors and your question aside, a class called `Color` should model a "Color" not a "list of colors", not using misleading names is essential

Comment: You're also inadvertently using typographic quotes like `”...“` instead of regular quotes like `"..."`. They look very close, but C++ cannot parse typographical quotes.

Comment: @tadman Nice spot, I was already wondering whether this question had been copied and pasted via Word, now I'm sure of it.

Comment: @Gah When you are preparing a question for stack overflow make sure the code you post is as close as poissble to the code you are really working with, copy and paste it from the text editor you use to write the code.

Comment: @john I edited the code again! I thought it would be too long if I copy and paste it here..I only learned char not string yet so I don't know how to store multiple words like {"red", "blue", "green"} not a single char array "red"..

Comment: @Gah You honestly should spend some time learning `std::string` and `std::vector` because these things are easier (and better) than the alternatives. Unfrotunately many C++ courses are taught the wrong way round. You learn the language as it developed historically, but unfortunately that means you learn the harder and more primitive stuff first.

Comment: You cannot change your question to display completely different code! That invalidates the answers. You should post a new question.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to store a variable length list of strings of variable length. C++ offers very useful objects for this in the standard library.

- [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/): a variable length list, properly managed.
- [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/): a variable length list of characters, all properly managed.

That way your code can be reduced to a simple:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Colors {
private:
    std::vector<std::string> colorList;
public:
    Colors(std::vector<std::string> const& colorList) : colorList(colorList) {}
};

int main() {
    Colors warm_colors({ "red", "pink", "orange", "yellow", "brown" });
    Colors cold_colors({ "green", "blue", "navy" });
}
```

Actually, in this case the constructor can be replaced by a move constructor:

```
Colors(std::vector<std::string>&& colorList) : colorList(std::move(colorList)) {}
```

... but that maybe too advanced for you yet.

Comment: Concise and thorough, nice!

Comment: yeah I was thinking to leave out things like initializer lists, constexpr, noexcept, and so on. He's a beginner.

Comment: Thank you but this is not something that I can use for my assignment yet since I'm not allowed to use what I've not learned yet :0 If I use anothe method...like an array of char pointer or string, what would I need to change from my code? I uploaded my current one, could you give me any advice? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Gah I feel sorry for you. It seems you have a bad teacher.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at your code you have some errors. Take the `Menu` constructor

```
Menu::Menu(const char* menuTitle, const char* items[], int numItems) {
    m_menuTitle = new char[strlen(menuTitle) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_menuTitle, strlen(menuTitle) + 1, menuTitle);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        m_items[i] = &items[i];
    }
    m_numItems = numItems;
}
```

You have correctly handled the menu title, now you should use the same ideas on the menu items. That is you allocate each menu item with new, and then you copy each menu item with strcpy_s. Like this

```
Menu::Menu(const char* menuTitle, const char* items[], int numItems) {
    m_menuTitle = new char[strlen(menuTitle) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_menuTitle, strlen(menuTitle) + 1, menuTitle);
    for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
        m_items[i] = new char[strlen(items[i]) + 1];
        strcpy_s(m_items[i], strlen(items[i]) + 1, menuTitle);
    }
    m_numItems = numItems;
}
```

See? It's really no different to what you had already, except that `m_items[i]` replaces `m_menuTitle`.